# IIS7 Directory Browsing reseting

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have a IIS 7 running where one of the sites is just a bunch of files exposed through Directory Browsing. I can enable it without any problems, but within a few hours the setting resets itself. Any idea what this could be caused by?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration being rolled back somehow, or not rolled back but simply changed in that regard, for some reason. Directory browsing doesn't just turn itself on or off; someone or something has to be taking action.

Edits to either system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config or a web.config file in the content directory (or at a level above it) are the most likely source of a configuration change.

Any changes to apphost.config will be backed up to \Inetpub\History , so can be reviewed in reverse there.

File auditing might be your best bet for working out what's doing it.

Incidentally, if IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility is installed, an older script or re-installer might be doing it.

Comment: Great answer, I'll be sure to check out the apphost.config History. I'm a developer and this is the customers machine, so I have limited rights.

Answer (score 0):

A possible issue is that Directory Browsing can be set in ApplicationHost.Config and also the local web.config.  If your development Web.Config doesn't have the Directory browsing setting and you publish your web site, you'll overwrite the setting.